# Do While loop Calculation in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a tricky Scenario here.
I have a value `A` and `B`, `B` is a sum of `X` and `Y` (`B=X+Y`), where `Y` should be 10% of `A+X`

Example:

If `A=40` and `B=15` Then I need a calculation which gives `X` and `Y` as

```
X=10
Y=5 (10% of A+X i.e 40+10=50)
```

Trying loop and Other reverse Calculation but no Luck!

Comment: Specify your question, A,B X, Y are variables, columns from some table or sth else?

Comment: This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What you want to get?

Comment: what values will be given to you, and what do you want to derive?

Comment: @SeanLange, thx for the link! bookmarked it...

Comment: What makes you think you need a loop? It looks like a scalar expression to me. Post what you've tried so far

Comment: A and B are derived Values after some Calculation Now B need to be derived into two values X and Y to make expression correct as Y is 5% of A+X. @MegaTron thx for Edit, Nick working on Format to paste the code

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @A DECIMAL(4,2) = 40;
DECLARE @B DECIMAL(4,2) = 15;

DECLARE @Y DECIMAL(4,2);
DECLARE @X DECIMAL(4,2);

SET @Y = (0.1 * @A + 0.1 * @B)/1.1;
SET @X = @B-@Y;
SELECT @X AS X, @Y AS Y;
```

Comment: will it be `SET @Y = (0.1 * @A + 0.1 * @B)/1.1;` or `SET @Y = (0.1 * @A + 0.1 * (@B-@Y))/1.1;`
as it reads Y is 5% of A+X i.e Y is 5% of A+(B-Y)